# Show or Hide other fields on the event of ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, loops, combobox

I have a ComboBox called Number of Candidates and I have 10 other comboBoxes, Upon selecting the number of candidates from the drop down menu that 10 ComboBoxes should be shown or hidden.

For example : I select number of candidates as 3 then ComboBox1 ComboBox2, ComboBox3 should be visible. If I select 2 then only ComboBox1 and ComboBox2 should be visible, rest should be hidden.

I have written below code which works fine for step up like 2 to 3, 3 to 5 like that.. For step down like 4 to 2 it won't work. Could you guys please help me

```
private void noOfCandidates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt16(noOfCandidates.SelectedItem);
            if (value == 1)
            {
                candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (value == 2)
            {
                candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
                candidateBox2.Visible = true; candidate3lbl.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (value == 3)
            {
                candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
                candidateBox2.Visible = true; candidate3lbl.Visible = true;
                candidateBox3.Visible = true; candidate4lbl.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (value == 4)
            {
                candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
                candidateBox2.Visible = true; candidate3lbl.Visible = true;
                candidateBox3.Visible = true; candidate4lbl.Visible = true;
                candidateBox4.Visible = true; candidate5lbl.Visible = true;
            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably need to add code to hide the controls that you don't want visible as well.

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
private void noOfCandidates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int value = Convert.ToInt16(noOfCandidates.SelectedItem);
   if (value == 1)
   {
      candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox2.Visible = false; candidate3lbl.Visible = false;
      candidateBox3.Visible = false; candidate4lbl.Visible = false;
      candidateBox4.Visible = false; candidate5lbl.Visible = false;
   }
   else if (value == 2)
   {
      candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox2.Visible = true; candidate3lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox3.Visible = false; candidate4lbl.Visible = false;
      candidateBox4.Visible = false; candidate5lbl.Visible = false;
   }
   else if (value == 3)
   {
      candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox2.Visible = true; candidate3lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox3.Visible = true; candidate4lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox4.Visible = false; candidate5lbl.Visible = false;
   }
   else if (value == 4)
   {
      candidateBox1.Visible = true; candidate2lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox2.Visible = true; candidate3lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox3.Visible = true; candidate4lbl.Visible = true;
      candidateBox4.Visible = true; candidate5lbl.Visible = true;
   }
}
```

I hope it was useful.

Comment: Wow, Thank you. Such simple ideas.